# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to pass an object from a project to an API Rest

Tags: java, rest, hadoop, hbase, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem with one of my project. Here is a little more info about it :

Our teacher gave us a virtual machine (ubuntu) which contains **Hadoop** and **Hbase**, already setup. 
The objective is pretty simple : we have a `Rest api` with `tomcat 8.5` (**RestServer** project, web project), which intercept `GET` requests (our teacher only want us to have `GET` request, security reason apparently), and we need to perform, according to the `url` (for instance : `/students/{id}/{program}` will return the grades summary for this particular student (id) and year of study (program)), data selection and mapreduce job on Hbase tables. And we have a **BigData** project, which contains simple java code to scan and filter `Hbase` table. Here is the short summary of the project.

Here is the structure we use for this project : [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozqWx.png)

And here is what is the execution logic : we type our `url` in the browser, after we launched our **RestServer** project (`right click on RestServer` -> `Run as` -> `Run on server`.
Here is what we get after doing so : [RestServer in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMOVN.png).

The easy part stop there. The links we see on the previous image are just for demo, they are not what we need to do in this project. The idea is to intercept the `GET` request from the api, in the method handling the request, get the parameters, give them to a call to the constructor of our response object, and return the object as the response (that will be transform into a `JSON`). The idea is to get this object (the response to our `GET` request) from the **BigData** project. So we need to make this 2 projects communicate.

Here is the code to intercept the request :

```
    @GET
    @Path("/students/{id}/{program}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getStudent(@PathParam("id") String ID,@PathParam("program") String program) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ID : "+ID+" program"+program);
        if (ID != null) {
            System.out.println("Non nul");
            return Response.ok(new Response1(ID,program), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Student not found: " + ID).build();
        }
    }
```

The `Response1(ID,program)` object is build in the **BigData** project. When i execute the code from the **BigData** project directly (as `Java application`), i have absolutely no problem, no error. But the idea is to use the code from the **BigData** project to build the `Result1` object, and "give it back" to the `Rest api`. The problem is here, i tried absolutely everything i know and found on the internet but i can't resolve this problem. When i type my url, (which is : `http://localhost:8080/RestServer/v1/StudentService/students/2005000033/L3`) i get this error : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxzl0.png)

From my research, i found that (correct me if i'm wrong) the program can't find the `ByteArrayComparable` class at `runtime`. I looked all the links i could find, and here is what i tried to resolve it :

- Check if the library for **Hadoop** and **Hbase** are in both projects.
- Check if the projects contains `hbase-client`, which is suppose to contains the `ByteArrayComparable` class (yes, it is in both projects).
- By doing `right click` on **RestServer** -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` :

  - `Source` tab : i added the `src` folder from **BigData** project (and `bin` folder, but i can't remember where, i believe it is in one of the tab of `Java Build Path`).
  - `Projects` tab : i added the **BigData** project.
  - `Order and Export` tab : i checked the `src` folder (this folder is in the **RestServer** project, created after i added the `src` folder from **BigData** project in the `Source` tab).
- `Deployement Assembly` : i added **BigData** project.
- I copied the class which are use in the **BigData** project in my `src` folder of my **RestServer** project.
- I saw that it can be cause by conflict between libraries, so i tried to remove some in one project and let them in the other.
- I cleaned and rebuilt the projects between each changes.
- I tried adding the import that seems to cause the problem by adding `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.*;` in the files that are involve in the execution.

I have no idea of what i can do now. Some of my friend have the same problem, even if we don't have the same code, so it seems that the problem come from the configuration. At this point, i didn't perform any mapreduce job, i'm just using `Hbase java api` to scan the table with some filters.

Thanks for reading me, i hope i'll find the answer. I'll keep testing and searching, and editing this post if i find something.

Here is the code for the `Response1` class :

```
package bdma.bigdata.project.rest.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter.*;

public class Response1 {
    private StudentBD student;
    private Semester semesters;

    public Response1(String id, String program) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Building student");
        this.student = new StudentBD(id);
        System.out.println("Building semester");
        this.semesters = new Semester(id,program);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return student.toString()+" "+semesters.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Response1 r = new Response1("2005000100", "L1");
        System.out.println("AFFICHAGE TEST");
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

I finally managed to resolve my problem. I put the solution here, if it can help someone in the same situation as mine in the futur.
Once you've linked your 2 projects (in the `Java Build Path` section of the properties of the `Rest api` project), you need to go, still in the properties, in the Deployment Assembly (above `Java Build Path`). Here you click on `Add...` and add all of your jar files.

Comment: Can you add the ```Response1``` class?

Comment: Done, i added the code @Vishal